# VGG16 Transfer Learning varying output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

Observed strange behavior when using VGG16 for transfer learning.

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=True)
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

new_layer = Dense(2,activation='softmax')
inp = model.input
out = new_layer(model.layers[-1].output)

model = Model(inp,out)
```

However, when `model.predict(image)` is used, the output is varying in terms of classification,i.e., sometime it classifies image as Class 1 and next time the same image is classified as Class 2.

Comment: It's very strange behaviour. Are you sure about this? Maybe you continue training the last layer?
Maybe images are not the same?

Comment: I am only using model.predict(image), can this also lead to training of intermediate layers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you didn't set seed. Try this

```
import numpy as np
seed_value = 0
np.random.seed(seed_value)

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=True)
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

new_layer = Dense(2, activation='softmax',
                  kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=seed_value),
                  bias_initializer=keras.initializers.Zeros())
inp = model.input
out = new_layer(model.layers[-1].output)

model = Model(inp,out)
```

Comment: can this be used during training also?

Comment: Yes. But If you initialize weights with different random state, there is a possibility that you can find better local minimum from time to time.